# Check if instance is of a type

Tags: c#, .net

Using this to check if `c` is an instance of `TForm`.

```
c.GetType().Name.CompareTo("TForm") == 0
```

Is there a more type safe way to do it besides using a `string` as a param to `CompareTo()`?

Comment: I certainly hope you don't do it in Java that way either.  Java's `instanceof` and C#'s `is` are much better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 503, accepted):

The different answers here have two different meanings.

If you want to check whether an instance is of *an exact type* then

```
if (c.GetType() == typeof(TForm))
```

is the way to go.

If you want to know whether `c` is an instance of `TForm` *or a subclass* then use `is`/`as`:

```
if (c is TForm)
```

or

```
TForm form = c as TForm;
if (form != null)
```

It's worth being clear in your mind about which of these behaviour you actually want.

Comment: A small note: use "is" if you don't want to use the result of the cast and use "as" if you do.

Comment: With C# 7 you can combine `is` and `as` with pattern matching: `if (x is TForm tf) {…`

Comment: @AviramFireberger you can not use the time with `if ( object is string s) `

Answer (score 50):

```
if(c is TFrom)
{
   // Do Stuff
}
```

or if you plan on using `c` as a `TForm`, use the following example:

```
var tForm = c as TForm;
if(tForm != null)
{
   // c is of type TForm
}
```

The second example only needs to check to see if `c` is of type `TForm` once. Whereis if you check if see if `c` is of type `TForm` then cast it, the CLR undergoes an extra check.
Here is a [reference](http://ekrishnakumar.wordpress.com/2006/07/08/c-is-and-as-operators/).

Edit: Stolen from Jon Skeet

If you want to make sure `c` is of `TForm` and not any class inheriting from `TForm`, then use

```
if(c.GetType() == typeof(TForm))
{
   // Do stuff cause c is of type TForm and nothing else
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the "is" keyword:

```
if (c is TForm)
{
    ...
}
```

See details on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(VS.80).aspx

> Checks if an object is compatible with a given type. For example, it can be determined if an object is compatible with the string type like this:

Answer (score 14):

A little more compact than the other answers if you want to use c as a TForm:

```
if(c is TForm form){
    form.DoStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Also, somewhat in the same vein

```
Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type c)
```

> "True if c and the current Type represent the same type, or if the
>   current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of c, or if the current
>   Type is an interface that c implements, or if c is a generic type
>   parameter and the current Type represents one of the constraints of c."

From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx

Comment: this is also my personal favorite.

`typeof(Class).IsAssignableFrom(object.getType())` similar to the Java `instanceof` operator.

Comment: Does it give false if they are not in the same branch of the inheritance hierarchy but a conversion operator exists?

Comment: Good question @PaulStelian. I am not sure off the top of my head but my guess would be it would return a false in that situation. That would at least be my expected behavior. Possibly if an implicit conversion exists it might return true but that would be odd.

Comment: Anyone who has Visual Studio installed to try it?

Comment: @PaulStelian - it returns false. This can be seen by following the doc link, and observing there is no mention of conversions. Another way to think about it is that `T1.IsAssignableFrom(T2)` returns `true` in situations where the `as` operator returns a non-null value, given instances of those types.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
if (c is TForm) { 
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the "is" keyword.  However, if you're going to later cast it to that type, eg.

```
TForm t = (TForm)c;
```

Then you should use the "as" keyword.

e.g.  `TForm t = c as TForm.`

Then you can check

```
if(t != null)
{
 // put TForm specific stuff here
}
```

Don't combine as with is because it's a duplicate check.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
c.getType() == typeOf(TForm)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bool isValid = c.GetType() == typeof(TForm) ? true : false;
```

or simpler

```
bool isValid = c.GetType() == typeof(TForm);
```

Comment: IMHO: I would avoid a direct compassion (ie. `==`). In object or oriented languages supporting inheritance unless you know that your specific Type will never be inherited from for instance a `sealed` Class.

Also: use of a ternary operator returning (static/constant) boolean values bothers me, I would be less bothered if it was a `switch` statement.