# Creating a generic list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics, object, quadtree

By way of an intro, I'm creating a basic Quadtree engine for personal learning purposes. I'm wanting this engine to have the capability of working with many different types of shapes (at the moment I'm going with circles and squares) that will all move around in a window and perform some sort of action when collision occurs.

Here are my shape objects as I have them so far:

```
public class QShape {
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public string colour { get; set; }
}

public class QCircle : QShape {
    public int radius;
    public QCircle(int theRadius, int theX, int theY, string theColour) {
        this.radius = theRadius;
        this.x = theX;
        this.y = theY;
        this.colour = theColour;
    }
}

public class QSquare : QShape {
    public int sideLength;
    public QSquare(int theSideLength, int theX, int theY, string theColour) {
        this.sideLength = theSideLength;
        this.x = theX;
        this.y = theY;
        this.colour = theColour;
    }
}
```

Now my question is, how do I create a generic list (`List<T> QObjectList = new List<T>();`) in C# so I can have one list containing all these various shapes that may have different properties (e.g., QCircle has the "radius" property while QSquare has the "sideLength" property)? An example of implementation would be helpful as well.

I just know that there is a stupidly obvious answer to this question but I'd appreciate any help anyway. I'm trying to get back into C#; it has obviously been a while...

Comment: List<QShape> ??

Comment: Would such a list include the classes that inherit from QShape? If so, I was right; the answer is stupidly obvious.

Comment: @Djentleman: Yes it would. But you'd only be able to access the QShape properties unless you cast the individual objects.

Comment: Could I get that in answer form, including an example of how you'd implement that (i.e., how you'd access QCircle and QSquare-specific properties from List<QShape>)?

Comment: @Djentleman You can't.  Not sure why his comment is being upvoted.  You clearly state you want to access different properties not contained in the parent class so using the base class as the type will not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use downcasting

Store the objects in a list with the base class

```
 List<QShape> shapes = new List<QShape>
```

You can then upcast the object safely if you know what it is e.g.

```
if(shapes[0] is QSquare)
{
     QSquare square = (QSquare)shapes[0]
}
```

You can also implicitly downcast objects

```
QSquare square = new Square(5,0,0,"Blue");
QShape shape =  square
```

[For more information read the Upcasting and Downcasting sections here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/polymorphcasting06222007131659PM/polymorphcasting.aspx)

Comment: If you're having to test types and cast when dealing with items in generic collections, it's a sign that something has gone wrong.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, its an alternative to an interface to access type specific properties.

Comment: I believe you can use the **is** keyword in your example, it's been available for quite some time.  if(myObject is MyType)

Comment: I learn a lot I didn't know on this site as well... everyday in fact, I think I learn something new.

Comment: I like this answer. Nice and simple. Thanks! Just a quick question on this, however; why would implicitly downcasting objects be useful?

Comment: Again, because if you are iterating over a list of `QShape`s you can't access properties/methods of `QSquare` or `QCircle`.  By checking in the if statement to see if it's a `QSquare` and casting it if it is you then have access to the properties/methods of `QSquare`.  The method in this answer is ok for checking a couple of classes but I'm sure you can see where it quickly gets out of hand if you start adding more and more subclasses.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the meaning of downcast. Great answer; very informative. Thank you.

Comment: @Joel note that `is` tests for assignment compatibility, not type equality, so it's not equivalent.  Specifically, for a subclass of QSquare, `x.GetType() == typeof(QSquare)` returns false, while `x is QSquare` returns true

Answer (score 3):

You should implement an `Interface`.  For example

```
public interface IHasLength
{
    int Length;
}
```

Then in the implementation you can do

```
public class QSquare : QShape, IHasLength {
    public int sideLength;
    public QSquare(int theSideLength, int theX, int theY, string theColour) {
        this.sideLength = theSideLength;
        this.x = theX;
        this.y = theY;
        this.colour = theColour;
    }
    public int Length { get { return sideLength; } }
}
public class QCircle : QShape, IHasLength {
    public int radius;
    public QSquare(int theSideLength, int theX, int theY, string theColour) {
        this.sideLength = theSideLength;
        this.x = theX;
        this.y = theY;
        this.colour = theColour;
    }
    public int Length { get { return radius; } }
}
```

FInally, in your list:

```
List<IHasLength> shapesWithSomeLength = new List<IHasLength>();
```

Now your list can hold ANYTHING that implements `IHasLength` whether it's a `QCircle`, `QShape`, or even a `QDuck` if you want as long as it implements `IHasLength`.

Comment: I like this answer, but is there any particular reason for using an interface as opposed to a superclass in this instance?

Comment: @Djentleman Because your classes don't have common property names.  So if you were to create a list of `QShape` and wanted to iterate over it and get the length for all shapes, `QCircle` and `QSquare` you can't.  If you implement the interface then you will be able to do just that.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Very nice. Time to read up on interfaces! Thanks :)

Comment: Just a quick note for your benefit. I've gone with this sort of approach except I've changed IHasLength to ISpatialNode. This interface is for x,y positioning. Makes more sense, and means I can add any object that requires positioning into my Quadtree.

Comment: @Djentleman Of course you want to use whatever names/properties makes sense for your implementation.  I just choose `Length` for the example since that's what you mentioned in your question (`radius`, `sideLength`).  I'm sure it's all clear by now ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could store them in a `List<QShape>` but this would mean that you could not access type-specific properties.

Generally, you might approach this by providing a common interface in your base class, and overriding behaviour in subclasses. In this way, a common interface can hide a diverse bunch of behaviours. For instance a `Grow` method could hide the complexities of growing items of different shape and could be called without explicit knowlege of the shape upon which it is operating.

```
public abstract class QShape {
    public abstract void Grow(int amt);
}
public class QSquare : QShape {
    private int sideLength;
    public override void Grow(int amt)
    {
        sideLength+=amt;
    }
}
public class QCircle : QShape {
    private int radius;
    public override void Grow(int amt)
    {
        radius+=amt;
    }
}
```

Comment: QShape should also be abstract.  Also, I don't see the use of an interface in your example.

Comment: I use the term interface in a loose fashion. All objects have an interface by virtue of offering methods and properties... not just those that inherit an `interface` implementation.

Comment: I like this, similar to Pete's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
public class QShape
{
    protected QShape() { }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public string colour { get; set; }
}

public class QCircle : QShape
{
    public int radius;
    public QCircle(int theRadius, int theX, int theY, string theColour)
    {
        this.radius = theRadius;
        this.x = theX;
        this.y = theY;
        this.colour = theColour;
    }
}

public class QSquare : QShape
{
    public int sideLength;
    public QSquare(int theSideLength, int theX, int theY, string theColour)
    {
        this.sideLength = theSideLength;
        this.x = theX;
        this.y = theY;
        this.colour = theColour;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<QShape> list = new List<QShape>();
        list.Add(new QCircle(100, 50, 50, "Red"));
        list.Add(new QCircle(100, 400, 400, "Red"));
        list.Add(new QSquare(50, 300, 100, "Blue"));


        foreach (var item in list.OfType<QCircle>())
        {
            item.radius += 10;
        }

        foreach (var item in list.OfType<QSquare>())
        {
            item.sideLength += 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One question: Wouldn't it be more efficient to iterate through the list once and perform actions on the different types using conditionals in said iteration, rather than iterating through it twice (once for each individual shape) as you have here?

Comment: @Djentleman: Yes, but...For small lists (<10,000 items) it probably makes no difference. It is really not clear from the OP what the goals/requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like i'm missing something but...

```
List<QCircle> circleObjects = new List<QCircle>();
```

and

```
List<QSquare> squareObjects = new List<QSquare>();
```

will work perfectly well.

EDIT:

Ah, I didn't understand what was being asked.

Yes, as your `QCircle` and `QSquare` classes inherit from `QShape`, you can just do.

```
List<QShape> shapes= new List<QShape>();
```

It's worth noting that if you want to access the `radius` property of all the `QCircle`'s in that list, then you are going to have to filter the list based on type.

Comment: The OP wants one List<T> which will include both. Therefore, it would be List<QShape>.

Comment: Yeah, that will work but he wants ONE list to hold any type of `QShape`, `QCircle`, and `QSquare`.

Comment: I should have been clearer, but I'm wanting a single list if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ian Mercer's comment `List<QShape>`

And here's how you would fill it:

```
List<QShape> shapes = new List<QShape>();
QCircle circle = new QCircle(); 

shapes.Add(circle);
```

To unbox it:

```
QCircle circle = (QCircle) shapes[0];
```

If you need to call a method off the base class, no need to unbox, just use it.

Comment: Good answer, very simple and yet informative. Joel's answer is similar but a bit more detailed, but thanks nonetheless!

Answer (score -1):

### Storing

You're already on the right track with your class definitions. What you have to do is make a `List` of the superclass (in this case, `QShape`), which will be able to hold all of your shapes.

Here's an example of how you would make it:

```
List<QShape> objects = new List<QShape>();

objects.add(new QCircle(...));
objects.add(new QSquare(...));
```

### Accessing

The problem here is differentiating what is what once everything is in the list. That's done with the `getType()` and `typeof()` methods of C#. ([Jon Skeet has an excellent answer about how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561202/check-if-instance-of-a-type)). Basically, it looks like this:

```
if(objects.get(some_position).getType() == typeof(QCircle))
  QCircle circle = objects.get(some_position);
else if(/* like above with QSquare */)
  QSquare square = objects.get(some_position);
```

After you do this, you can resume using your objects like normal. But if you try accessing them from the list, you can only use the methods and variables that `QShape` has, as every object put in the list will be cast to it.

Comment: WTF is objects.get().getType() ??  And why not just shorten it to if(myObject is MyType)

Comment: While some of your syntax may appear to be off, I understand what you were saying, so thanks!

Comment: @ChrisGessler testing an object's type for equality with a known type is not the same as the `is` operator (and 99% of the time the programmer wanted the behavior of the `is` operator, anyway, so the type equality check is usually a bug).

Answer (score -1):

```
public Class abstract  Base<T>
{
    public abstract List<T>GetList();
}
```

then do this

```
public class className:Base<ObjectName>
{
    public override List<T>GetList()
    {
        //do work here 
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful.